# Django Inserting data (Getting correct data)

Tags: django

I have this code in my html

```
<form method="post" id="DogForm" action="/studentbehavior/"  class="myform" style="width: 100%" enctype="multipart/form-data">{% csrf_token %}
    <table class="tblcore">
    <input type="hidden" value="{{teacher}}" name="teacher">
        <tr>
            <td rowspan="2" colspan="2">Core Values</td>
            {% for core in corevalues %}
                <td colspan="8"><input type="hidden" value="{{core.id}}" name="core">{{core.Description}}</td>
            {% endfor %}
        </tr>
        <tr>
            {% for corevalues in corevaluesperiod %}
                <td colspan="4" style="font-size: 12px"><input type="hidden" value="{{corevalues.id}}" name="coredescription">{{corevalues.Description}}</td>
            {% endfor %}
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2">Student's Name</td>
            {% for corevalues in period %}
            <td colspan="4">
                <input type="hidden" value="{{corevalues.id}}" name="coreperiod">Q {{corevalues.id}}
            </td>
                        <td colspan="4">
                <input type="hidden" value="{{corevalues.id}}" name="coreperiod">Q {{corevalues.id}}
            </td>
                        <td colspan="4">
                <input type="hidden" value="{{corevalues.id}}" name="coreperiod">Q {{corevalues.id}}
            </td>
                        <td colspan="4">
                <input type="hidden" value="{{corevalues.id}}" name="coreperiod">Q {{corevalues.id}}
            </td>
                        <td colspan="4">
                <input type="hidden" value="{{corevalues.id}}" name="coreperiod">Q {{corevalues.id}}
            </td>
                        <td colspan="4">
                <input type="hidden" value="{{corevalues.id}}" name="coreperiod">Q {{corevalues.id}}
            </td>
                        <td colspan="4">
                <input type="hidden" value="{{corevalues.id}}" name="coreperiod">Q {{corevalues.id}}
            </td>
        {% endfor %}
        </tr>
        {% for students in student %}
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2" class="names"><input type="hidden" value="{{students.id}}" name="student">{{students.Students_Enrollment_Records.Students_Enrollment_Records.Students_Enrollment_Records.Student_Users}}</td>
            <td colspan="4">
                <select name="marking">
                    <option>--------</option>
                    {% for m in marking %}
                        <option value="{{m.Marking}}" >{{m.Marking}}</option>
                    {% endfor %}
                </select>
            </td>
            <td colspan="4">
                <select  name="marking">
                    <option  >--------</option>
                    {% for m in marking %}
                        <option value="{{m.Marking}}">{{m.Marking}}</option>
                    {% endfor %}
                </select>
            </td>
            <td colspan="4">
                <select  name="marking">
                    <option>--------</option>
                    {% for m in marking %}
                        <option value="{{m.Marking}}">{{m.Marking}}</option>
                    {% endfor %}
                </select>
            </td>
            <td colspan="4">
                <select  name="marking">
                    <option>--------</option>
                    {% for m in marking %}
                        <option value="{{m.Marking}}">{{m.Marking}}</option>
                    {% endfor %}
                </select>
            </td>
            <td colspan="4">
                <select name="marking">
                    <option>--------</option>
                    {% for m in marking %}
                        <option value="{{m.Marking}}">{{m.Marking}}</option>
                    {% endfor %}
                </select>
            </td>
            <td colspan="4">
                <select name="marking">
                    <option>--------</option>
                    {% for m in marking %}
                        <option value="{{m.Marking}}">{{m.Marking}}</option>
                    {% endfor %}
                </select>
            </td>
            <td colspan="4">
                <select name="marking">
                    <option>--------</option>
                    {% for m in marking %}
                        <option value="{{m.Marking}}">{{m.Marking}}</option>
                    {% endfor %}
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
        {% endfor %}
    </table>
    <input type="submit" value="Insert" id="submit">
</form>
```

this is what its looks like in web view

[image]

this is my code in my views where the data inserted

```
def studentbehavior(request):
    id = request.POST.get('teacher')
    teacher = EmployeeUser(id=id)

    coreid = request.POST.get('core')
    core = CoreValues(id=coreid)

    corevalues = []
    for corevaluesid in request.POST.getlist('coredescription'):
        corevalues.append(corevaluesid)



    coreperiodID = request.POST.get('coreperiod')
    coreperiod = gradingPeriod(id = coreperiodID)

    marking = []
    for markingID in request.POST.getlist('marking'):
        marking.append(markingID)
        print(marking.append(markingID))
    for m in request.POST.getlist('marking'):
        for student in request.POST.getlist('student'):
            students = StudentPeriodSummary(id=student)
        #s = marking[m]
            for desc in request.POST.getlist('coredescription'):
                coredescription = CoreValuesDescription(id=desc)
                V_insert_data = StudentsCoreValuesDescription(
                    Teacher=teacher,
                    Core_Values=coredescription,
                    Marking=m,
                    Students_Enrollment_Records=students,
                    grading_Period=coreperiod,
                )
                V_insert_data.save()
        return render(request, "Homepage/updatebehavior.html")
```

this my problem, all markings saved to the datavase even if I select only one in the selection box, (in admin view), looks like the data entering in the database is incorrect.

[image]

this is my desire answer

[image]

**UPDATE**

WHEN I try the answer of mr@Saisiva A

```
for m, student, desc in zip(request.POST.getlist('marking'), request.POST.getlist('student'),
                             request.POST.getlist('coredescription')):
    coredescription = CoreValuesDescription(id=desc)
    students = StudentPeriodSummary(id=student)
    V_insert_data = StudentsCoreValuesDescription(
        Teacher=teacher,
        Core_Values=coredescription,
        Marking=m,
        Students_Enrollment_Records=students,
        grading_Period=coreperiod,
    )
    V_insert_data.save()
```

this is the data i inputted

[image]

this is the result i received in my admin site

[image]

**Update**

I am selecting a mark for every student and every core value then sending all data back to the server

If i want to input like this

[image]

the result inserted in my database is like this

[image]

UPDATE AGAIN when i try to add this to my views

```
for markingID in request.POST.getlist('marking'):
    marking.append(markingID)


print(marking[m])
```

the error says

**list indices must be integers or slices, not str**

Comment: How are you saving this data? are you selecting a mark for every student and every core value then sending all data back to the server?

How do you know which mark is for which student and which marks is for what core value? To me it looks like you're just looping all marks then all students then all core values then updating them. There's no reference that this mark is for this student.

Comment: i loop the marking on the student loop, am @crimson589 what should i do to get it right? in a proper way , please help me sir

Comment: Well currently you're just getting a list of everything you have, there's no structure in your data. I would try building a json object first in your html page using javascript. Something like `[{StudentID1: {CoreID1: Mark, CoreID2: Mark}}, {StudentID2: {CoreID1: Mark, CoreID2: Mark}}]`. This way  you can loop this object in your view and update each student 1 by 1.

Comment: can you please gives example on how to do it? i dont understand, and i dont know how to do it

Comment: Mmmm... sorry but I don't have access to a development PC right now to try some code. If you're open to using jquery, the basic logic is to loop every student hidden input first, that's where you're going to get `{StudentID1 :`. Then loop through every Core value id and their mark.

Comment: sad :( ........

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
    marking = []
    for markingID in request.POST.getlist('Marking'):
        marking.append(markingID)

    for i, mark in enumerate(request.POST.getlist('Marking')):
        s = StudentBehaviorMarking(id=mark)
        core = corevalues[i]
        cores = EducationLevelGradingBehavior(id=core)
        print("mark", mark, "per description", core)
        for student in request.POST.getlist('student'):
            students = StudentPeriodSummary(id=student)
            V_insert_data = StudentsBehaviorGrades(
                Teacher=teacher,
                # Education_Levels
                Students_Enrollment_Records=students,
                Grading_Period=coreperiod,
                Grading_Behavior=cores,
                Marking=s,
            )
            V_insert_data.save()
```

Answer (score 0):

Just modify the code in below format

```
for m, students, desc in zip(request.Post.getlist('marking'), request.Post.getlist('student'), request.Post.getlist('coredescription')):
     V_insert_data = StudentsCoreValuesDescription(
                    Teacher=teacher,
                    Core_Values=coredescription,
                    Marking=m,
                    Students_Enrollment_Records=students,
                    grading_Period=coreperiod,
                )
                V_insert_data.save()
        return render(request, "Homepage/updatebehavior.html")
```

Comment: It saves all record, it still the same

Comment: Its modified check it out - @justin

Comment: i get this error """WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'post'""

Comment: oops, Its capital P - request.Post - @justin

Comment: please check my question sir

Comment: @justin, can i know based on your input, what output should come?

Comment: wait i will post it

Comment: please check now

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209127/discussion-between-justin-and-saisiva-a).